# Why is there a difference in performance across the feature descriptors for the same imaging modality?

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I've been using GIST, HOG and SURF descriptors for extracting features from different collections of Chest-X-rays and measuring performance using accuracy and area under the curve. These collections are obtained using different machinery, from different medical institutions, and, with different pixel resolutions. I could repeatedly see that one descriptor performs better than the other and the performance is not the same across these collections though all are frontal chest X-rays. What attributes to these differences in performance across the collections though they are from the same imaging modality?

Comment: What are the differences between the collections? For example: Are the X-Rays taken using different machinery/techniques? Are some old archived material, some very recent? Do they show different problems (e.g. some broken ribs, some lung cancer)? Are they just from different medical institutions? When you say "performance", what are you measuring - classification accuracy?

Comment: I'm measuring performance using accuracy and area under the curve. As you have rightly mentioned, these collections are obtained using different machinery, from different medical institutions, and, with different pixel resolutions. Are these the contributing factors for the difference in performance across the descriptors with the different datasets?

Comment: I think that it is very likely that each collection presents different challenges and will be easier/harder to work with as a result. I suspect even human doctors feel that way when asked to interpret the pictures! Please could you add that detail to your question using the [edit] link. There is no need to mark it as a change, the site tracks your edit history.

Comment: Thanks for that useful comment. As per your suggestions, I have edited the question, adding more details.

Answer (score 1):

Feature-extraction mechanisms like GIST, HOG, etc are built and optimized to improve performance on given datasets.  Because of this, they don't perform as well across datasets.  It's kind of like putting specialized fuel in a vehicle that isn't built to utilize it - it might even do harm.

Hand-engineered features are, as a rule, brittle.  I once heard it said that the dirty secret of machine learning is just knowing how to transform your domain-specific information into meaningful features - after that, you can use an extremely simple classifier and it may do surprisingly well.  The drawback is that the rules you built are very specific to your domain.

Deep neural networks, and convolutional neural networks in particular, are an advancement in that they *learn* what features are useful about raw data - for CNNs, these are the raw pixel or time-series values.  Instead of hand-building feature extraction mechanisms, these architectures *automatically* build them.

One benefit of this is that if you use a CNN to identify images in general, you can re-use the top few feature extraction layers of the CNN on a different image recognition dataset, and re-train the bottom few layers to make the network specific to recognizing e.g. dog breeds.  You can transfer what you learned about the statistical structure of natural images in general to other, more specific questions (general -> specific).  In your case, the 'top few layers' are analogous to your GIST/HOG methods - and they wouldn't be expected to perform well when the task changes, because they were constructed for a specific task (specific -> other specific).